# How to set position of a Wayland client's surface in Weston background?

Tags: position, wayland

I create a Wayland shell surface to show "FPS info".
[image: I would like to position windows like this]

Now, I would like to set fixed position for this wayland client while starting the application.
How can I do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set fixed position of text displaying window by using

```
wl_shell_surface_set_transient (wl_shell_surface, wl_surface, POS_X, POS_Y, 0);
wl_shell_surface_set_toplevel(wl_shell_surface);
```