# How to get the position of a wayland window on the screen?

Tags: wayland

Can the position of a window be accessed from wayland?

The only information available on this topic mentions accessing positional information based on a parent window, but this isn't always practical (when there are multiple top-level windows for example).

Is it possible to read the window location in relation to an output? (for example).

---

Note that this is the inverse of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67318357).